Joomla 5 - Should I use Gzip AND Brotli?
Joomla allows the control of Gzip in the administrator section, and I also run most sites through Cloudflare.
My UK hosting allows Brotli as a PHP extension, but should I run it if Gzip is enabled within Joomla?
To complicate matters, Cloudflare is moving to Brotli enabled by default soon, so there will be no choice but to run with Brotli enabled via the CDN. I guess this means it is then best to disable the PHP extenson in my hosting...but surely Brotli as a PHP extension is better than Cloudflare <-- this is pure assumption!
So, to recap
Joomla sites run 'best' with GZip enabled
Should I run Brotli at all?
DO I disable Gzip if Cloudflare is forcing sites to run Brotli
Do I disable Brotli in PHP if Cloudflare is forcing Brotli
It's tricky to encapsulate the problem so I hope someone understands my circular issue!
Using a dev server site build (So Brotli is PHP extension here)
I tried
Gzip and Brotli disabled - Lighthouse performance 97
Gzip enabled Brotli disabled - Lighthouse performance 98
Gzip disabled Brotli enabled  - Lighthouse performance 98
Gzip and Brotli enabled - Lighthouse performance 98
Is it this simple?

The difference between Gzip and Brotli is debatable and subject to opinion. The difference between "compression" and "no comrpession" is fairly definitive that compressing your HTTP responses is a significant network performance gain and bandwidth savings.

Besides that, what compression Cloudflare uses to deliver content to users is irrelevant to what Cloudflare uses to talk to backend servers, which will be "whatever the backend implements". Similarly Cloudflare can't force clients to use a compression method they don't support. All Cloudflare is doing is making Brotli one of the compression methods available for selection by browsers.
